# How to control Android phone from Mac?

Tags: macos, android, remote-control

I own an old android phone with broken touch screen. Is there any way to control it from my Mac? (by controlling I mean 'touching screen', pressing back and home buttons)

(haven't found bluetooth mouse to use it with the phone)

Comment: "broken" is ambiguous; You should specify to what extent the screen is damaged/"broken", as that information would be required in order to recommend a solution. You should also specify which version of Android your phone is running, the make and model of your phone, the version of your OS, what model/type of "Mac" you are using, and what year your Mac was initially released. There are many potential solutions for controlling an Android phone with a Mac, but there's no way to know which solution (if any) works in your case without knowing the information mentioned before.

Answer (score 1):

[Vysor](https://www.vysor.io/) should work. You can either download it as an application on your Mac, or install it as an app for Google Chrome.